# Flex disconnect with server after 1 hour

Tags: apache-flex, iis

I developed a application using Flex and VB.NET.
Flex requests to server some operation that build by VB.NET.
but, if it takes long over 1 hour, then it disconnects with server after 1 hour.
I want it to keep until completing it even if it takes several hours.
I use IIS 7.5. 
I don't know where it forces to disconnects from, it is from IIS or from Flex.
Who knows where can I configure this time from?
I will appreciate if you give me any clue.

Comment: I would expect such a timeout to be a browser setting; and I'm surprised the connection stays open for a full hour.  Maybe you should look into using some form of server side push to let the client know when the server is ready.  WebORB should have a .NET solution for server-side-push.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found out Explorer disconnect after 1 hour.it is default timeout time.and, it is configured to different time in regstry.